# If $W$ is a subspace of the finite-dimensional vector space $V$, show that $W^* \cong V^*/A(W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, duality-theorems

If $W$ is a subspace of the finite-dimensional vector space $V$, show that $W^* \cong V^*/A(W)$. Conclude that $\dim A(W) = \dim V - \dim W$.

Hint: Define a map $\psi: V^* \rightarrow W^*$ by $\psi(\phi) = \phi\vert_{W}$ and show that $\psi$ is surjective with ker$\psi$ = $A(W)$. Now apply the theorem $V / \ker \psi \cong \psi(V)$.

---

What I know:

- For $W$ to be a subspace of $V$ it must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication over $V$.
- $V^* / A(W)$ is the quotient space of $V^*$ and $A(W)$ where $V^*/A(W)$ = {$\bar{v};v\in V$} where $\bar{v} = v + A(W) = $ {$v+a; a\in A(W)$}.
- $V^*$ means the dual space of $V$ which means that it is the set of all linear maps $\phi: V\rightarrow k$
- If $f: V → k$ is a linear map, then $f\vert_{W}$ means the linear map $W → k$ given by the same formula as $f$. (in other words, just shrink the domain of $f$)
- $A(W)$ means the set of $\phi \in V^*$ such that $\phi(w) = 0$ for every $w \in W$. (The annihilator of $W$)

I'm just having trouble putting all of this information into a cohesive proof.

Comment: Isn't $\;W^0\;$ a standard notation for annihilator of $\;W\;$ ?

Comment: My book defines it as A(W) but I'm sure like many mathematical operations there are different ways to define things

Comment: It's too far past my bedtime for me to write an answer, but let me give you some hints. An element of the dual space is determined by its values on a basis. You can take a basis for $W$ and extend it to a basis for $V$. Thus you can map $W^*$ into $V^*$ by defining the functional to be 0 on the basis elements not in $W$. Now map $V^*$ to $V^*/A(W)$, and show the composition is injective and surjective.